# How to INSERT INTO table from SELECT without specifying columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Not sure if it's possible at all, especially after scrutinizing [some info on the Internet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776381%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). I'd like to rewrite the following as not to have to specify the columns at all, if possible. Second hand happiness would be having a generic set of columns that accept everything else, independent of type nor number.

The reason for that is, of course, that I'm lazy, sick and tired of rewriting the holder *beep* for each, single case.

```
declare @beep table(Hazaa int)
insert into @beep
select WholeSomeValue from ThisOrThatTable
```

That'd be nice to be able to use something like this.

```
declare @beep table(GenericColumns ???)
insert into @beep
select * from ThisOrThatTable
```

Or, at least, like so.

```
declare @beep table(GenericColumn1 ???, GenericColumn2 ???, GenericColumn3 ???)
insert into @beep
select Col1, Col2, Col3 from ThisOrThatTable
```

Comment: That is quite sad. You posted a question on a forum because you are lazy and want to avoid writing explicit code? You should ALWAYS specify the column list in your insert AND your select statements. There is no shortcut for writing solid code. Intellisense makes this kind of thing quite simple.

Comment: @SeanLange I'm not blessed with intellisense. Also, this code is for probing the DB while trying to figure out some things. In the deliverable code, I'd never do such a thing. Thanks for pointing that out. I forgot to mention that detail in the question.   :)

Comment: *Second hand happiness would be having a generic set of columns that accept everything else, independent of type nor number*, then why use a relational database at all?, you can use excel or a flat file

Comment: @Lamak I'm probing a DB to see what values I can pick up in order to recognize something. Then, I'll need to plug in those values to keep looking for others. It's quite poorly documented and the naming leaves a lot to wish. Also, I'm not sure I even have Excel on this computer not that it'd do me much good at this stage, hehe.)

Comment: @SeanLange If you think the OP's question or approach is bad, you should either downvote, or make a constructive comment explaining what's wrong.  There is absolutely no need to insult someone on this site.

Comment: @jadarnel27 I was not intending to insult the OP. I just commented that I felt it rather sad. The rest was directly from the OP. And I did in fact offer constructive advice. I can how it would taken as an insult and I will try to more careful.

Comment: @KonradViltersten My apologies. I was not trying to be insulting but reading my comment it certainly was. Strike the first two sentences and I stand behind my comments. Not having intellisense is kind of a pain. I assume you must be on 2005 or earlier. You can always use SSMS or QA (if you are still on 2000) to generate a list of columns quite painlessly just by dragging the "Columns" folder to your query window.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up, @SeanLange - and for engaging in this constructive dialogue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about using a temporary table? You don't have to know the structure in advance.

```
select 
 t.* 
into #beep
from ThisOrThatTable as t
```

Comment: I've been instructed to use **declared** instead of **temporary** tables with basis of the former being "*better*" than the latter (without an actual specification of in what way that "*betterness*" would exhibit). I'm open to going by your suggestion, though.

Comment: @KonradViltersten better how?, please read [this](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16385/whats-the-difference-between-a-temp-table-and-table-variable-in-sql-server) link to understand clearly what are the differences between a temp table and a table variable

Comment: This answer is merely predicated on, "facilitate my laziness." This is as easy as I can make it. The only way to use a table variable would be to leverage dynamic SQL to build up the declaration (column-names, types, etc) from the schema. That's a little more complicated than it would seem you'd like.

Comment: @canon I think I wasn't clear. I **love** your reply (can't check it as an answer yet, though). I was just explaining why I didn't went for the temporary option. Also, I wanted to check with you of there was some huge disadvantage to using temps that I forgot to ask about. There's absolutely nothing I can see as insufficient or wrong with your answer, matie. Just the good stuff, there.

Comment: @Lamak Better how? It says in my comment. There you see the **precise** grounds I've been presented with from my supervisor.   :)

Comment: There are various factors which should inform the comparison between temporary tables and table variables. How much data is involved? Are the temporary tables indexed? How are they to be used? How much use is tempdb getting in general? Anyone who gives you a simple "one is good, one is bad" answer is doing you a disservice.

Comment: Agreed! I was sarcastic in my comment. I got a "*do this - it's better*". When I asked in what way I got a frown back. As for the data, it's just me poking around so pretty much anything will do. It's +1 to you shortly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own custom [table type](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522526(v=sql.105).aspx):

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.Beep AS TABLE 
(
    Column1 INT,
    Column2 VARCHAR(50)
)
```

Then use it like this:

```
DECLARE @beep dbo.Beep

INSERT INTO @beep 
SELECT 1, 'blah'

SELECT * FROM @beep
```

Comment: Thanks. How does that resolve my issue of not wanting to redesign the temporary table for each different reading? I'm not very good at SQL so I'm simply missing it.   :)

Comment: I started writing this before you updated your question so it doesn't really help any more :)

Comment: Not reading minds, are we? Shame on you!  (Seriously, though - my bad. Sorry. +1 for helpful suggesting at **that** time.)

Comment: I guess that counters the random downvote I got for it too haha. I'll leave it on here anyway as it's quite a cool feature.

Comment: Just for the record - downvote isn't from me. I (almost) never downvote. In fact, you got +1 from me as explained above.